# how to create duplicate xml $writer element with php

Tags: php, xml

working on order xml to dropship to  supplier they want to have products added in the amount quantity so not

the part of the xmlwriter is when the order button is pushed and the admin gets admin alert

but i really cant see or find the code that would do it tbh

```
foreach ($order_products as $order_product) {

$writer->startElement("products");

$writer->writeElement('art', $order_product['model']);
$writer->writeElement('quantity',$order_product['quantity']);
// what i thought of was 

$order_product['quantity'] * $writer->writeElement('art', $order_product['model']);  ;
// something like that really dont know where to start with this one

$writer->endElement();

}

what the suplier wants is if quantity is 3

<product>1234</product><product>1234</product><product>1234</product>
```

Comment: Do you want to call `$writer->writeElement('art', $order_product['model']);` multiple times given the value in `$order_product['quantity']` ? if so, a simple for loop can be used here to create repetition -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add `<art>` multiple times based on `quantity`, just create a for loop:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $order_product['quantity']; $i++ )
{
  $writer->writeElement( 'art', $order_product['model'] );
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: i really thought that wouldnt work with xml and php, i go try it right away couldnt find this in php xmlwriter manual

Comment: Well the manual is going to state how to write a single element, how you extend and work around problems is what makes you a developer :) Just think, each time writeElement is called it's going to write an element regardless of what value you feed it. It doesn't care if its the same value or random values over and over. eg https://3v4l.org/73KEP